# How to make chrome display on the top opened in selenium [Mac OS X]

Tags: macos, google-chrome, selenium, browser, robotframework

When I use Firefox browser then the window is on top, but for Chrome it is not.
So, how can I make Chrome window be on top?

I have seen the `selenium2library\keyword\_browsermanagement.py`, but can't find any useful keyword(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Get Window Identifiers, Get Window Names, Get Window Titles, List Windows keywords available in the Selenium2Library?  If you've success with one of them, you should them be able to Select Window and bring it to the forefront.

We could use a bit more context in your question, do you have multiple browsers open at once?  If so, why?

Comment: firstly, no matter I open one browser or multiple browser, chrome will not display in the forefront ,and Select Windows keyword is effective as you said.

Comment: Secondly, I found that when I run my test script in OSX’s Terminal, Chrome will at the forefront directly, I use iTerm2 before, so I think the problem may come from the way open browser of different command.  Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: if the above solution worked for you, can you please accept the answer to help others?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution worked for our project.
Before driver.get(url) we execute the following command:

```
osascript -e tell application "${browserName}"
   activate
   delay 1
   end tell
```

*browserName* could be safari/chrome/firefox