# Robot Framework - Selenium2Library - Chrome & Edge open new tab instead of window

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

Sorry if this is a mundane question.

My issue is that the user can click on the "Help" button, which by default will open in a new tab, the help page.

When firing the test in Firefox, it creates a new window. Which is great as I can use the Select Window keyword and give it the URL. However, with Chrome and Edge, it just makes a new tab.

I read that Tabs aren't supported - But the weird part is, the test on Edge passes fine, it is just Chrome which is having the problem. Is there a reason behind that?

Is there a way to force it to be a Window and not a Tab? Or something?

I read that I can input a keyboard shortcut of CTRL + Tab. But that feels really dirty and would prefer a better way of doing it.

Error:

ValueError: Unable to locate window with URL 'http://...

**EDIT**

OK - So instead of using the URL param, I tried the title instead. Just on a whim. And it worked (?) I have no idea how it worked and why using the URL didnt and the title did: Here are the lines I used:

```
Run Keyword If    '${Browser}' == 'Chrome'
    ...    Select Window    1.7.1 User Guide
    ...    ELSE
    ...    Select Window    1.7.1 User Guide - Welcome to the User Guide
```

Still though, both the "Gets" did not produce a link to the newly created tab / window though :/ - Many thanks to shicky and Helio!

Comment: After Staring at everything for a while. Turns out, Chrome handles spaces differently to Edge + FF. The Chrome link does not have %20 for its spaces where Edge and FF do. Meaning two different URL.

So I created a If statement saying if the browser var is set to Chrome then use the other link. But it still isn't switching over.. Back to square one..

Comment: Try to get windows handles (`Get Window Identifiers` or `Get Window Names`)

Answer (score 1):

Are tabs not handled largely the same as windows?  You should be able to identify what is on the screen as @Helio says by using one of the following:

```
Get Window Identifiers
Get Window Names
```

Here are some similar questions that should help you get started, post back here with some further detail if you need more help.

[How to get the current URL in Robot framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833624/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-robot-framework)

[How to make chrome display on the top opened in selenium [Mac OS X]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197800/how-to-make-chrome-display-on-the-top-opened-in-selenium-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thank you Shicky and Helio, Ill investigate shortly and post any findings :)

Comment: @goralight did you have any success?

Comment: I just realised that shortly doesn't mean a week D: Sorry - I will definitely look today. Got carried away with other tests as you've seen! Thanks for keeping up with it though!

Comment: no worries, glad to help out where I can.  Let us all know how you get on

Comment: OK. So. After running both the Get Window Identifiers and Get Window Names. It does not display anything for the newly created tab. For example: 

Altogether 2 items.
1: selenium_main_app_window
2: xxx

Comment: Editted question for my own solution - dont thnk this will help anyone else however ...

Comment: Why is new tab a problem?  Surely it's going to be top of the stack anyway?  Seems getting the windows was exactly what you needed, just that you needed to use a different identifier?

Comment: Yes it was on top of the stack, but it wasnt getting focus, so I still had to select the window, which is where all this came from. But I still dont understand why it works for Title but not for the URL.

Comment: I've always used title I'm afraid as it seemed most natural, never used URL

Comment: most important is that you've resolved your issue though, well done on trying different things, most wouldn't have tried!